# Получение user id с занесением в txt файл. Python, telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Я пишу бота и мне нужно получать ID пользователя и заносить его в .txt файл. Как это сделать? Желательно скрипт к команде /start. Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Вот Ваш скрипт:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    test=open('test.txt', 'w')
    test.write(str(message.from_user.id))
    test.close()
```

Comment: Помогло? Пишите в комментариях

Comment: у меня работает,  у автора вопроса тоже должно работать.

Comment: Да, но я жду, пока _сам_ автор ответит

Comment: Если помог ответ, поставьте галочку и "лайк" =)